Trying to create a bar chart that gets the total money spent on each purchase grouped by gender and date
I am trying to create a bar chart that answers the question: Which gender spent the most money each year? I have a dataset that has each transaction listed with money spent, gender (male, female, other), and date (10-16-2014, 9-8-2015, 7-29-2016, etc.) attached to each entry. I want create a bar stacked bar chart that shows the total amount spent by each gender, every year (just the year). Please Help!
This is what I have so far (Doesn't work):
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style = "white", color_codes=True)
sales = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/mobile-sales-dataset/mobile_sales.csv")


sales.groupby(['CustomerGender'])['TotalRevenue'].sum()
genders =["Male","Female","Other"]
w = 0.2
xp = range(len(genders))

plt.bar(xp,genders)
#p1 = plt.bar(bar1, male, w, label = "Male")
#p2 = plt.bar(bar2, female, w, label = "Female")
#p3 = plt.bar(bar3, other, w, label = "Other")

plt.ylabel('Total Revenue')
plt.title('Total Revenue by Gender')
plt.xticks(xp,x)
plt.legend()
plt.show()


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, so what do you want to ask? What's the problem exactly? This is out of my wheelhouse so I'm not going to try to get more detailed, but "Doesn't work" is not descriptive enough. Please read [ask] and [edit] to clarify. You might need to make a [mre] including example pandas data.

I have found that I have to register with Kaggle to download your dataset, and I won't. Could you post the dataset somewhere else? The Apache license permits it.

First mistake is the groupby() function, which returns a data frame. You need to assign it to a variable as you're not changing sales if you just type sales.groupby(...
You also don't have to define your own x-axis, the groupby() function and matplotlib will do that for you. This should work:
grouped_sales = sales.groupby('CustomerGender')['TotalRevenue'].sum()
plt.bar(grouped_sales.index, grouped_sales.values)

plt.ylabel('Total Revenue')
plt.title('Total Revenue by Gender')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


When you perform a groupby function on a dataframe, it will return a new dataframe, so you need to assign it to a variable.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

path = 'path/to/your/file'
sales = pd.read_csv(path)
sales['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sales['Date'])
sales['Year'] = sales['Date'].dt.year
grouped_data = sales.groupby(['Year', 'CustomerGender'])['TotalRevenue'].sum().unstack()
ax = grouped_data.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(12, 6))

plt.title('Total Revenue by Gender and Year')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Total Revenue')
plt.legend(title='Gender')
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

